# integrate a chat in a web-app powered by Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, chat

I am developing a Web-app with Angular (client-side) and Node (server-side). I'd like to integrate some social features, including a chat. So a user can discover near users and send them a message.
I want to know the best way to implement this. I have an idea, but it seems to me very raw, and I am afraid that it could overload the server.

1. my idea is to send each minute from the client, a request to the
   server about new messages
2. the server looks for new messages among
   all the conversations of that user, checking the last-message's 
   time for each conversation
3. the server sends back the conversations
   with new messages
4. if the client receives conversations with new messages, a
   notification appears, so the user can open the chat.
5. once the chat is opened, the request to the server for 
   new messages is sent each 3 seconds (instead of 1 minute)

Example of conversations of a user, stored in MongoDB

```
{'conversations':    
 [
  {'to':{'user-id':'101010', 'name':'Michela', 'location':'Alba Adriatica', 
         'img':'http://graph.facebook.com...jpg'
         }, 
   'last-msg':12345, //epoch
    'msgs':[
            {'from-me':'ciao come stai?', 'date':''},
            {'from-you':'bene grazie, tu?', 'date':''},
            {'from-me':'eh insomma..mi so rott lu cazz', 'date':''},
            {'from-you':'dai poi vai alle Hawaii', 'date':''}
           ]
   },
   ...
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You realy should learn about websockets and how they can provide 'push and pull' of information.

the approach your suggesting called 'long polling'. And yes, if the time between is not very long, the server will be under heavy load if the number of clients increases.

Using websockets you can let the server communicatie only with the clients that actually need the information.

Do a google search for "node.js chat application tutorial". It is not that difficult.

Comment: So, I can use sockets for the users with the chat opened, and use the 'long polling' just to check if someone has sent a new message. With the sockets, I can still serve many users at the same time? I mean, the server can handle many sockets opened, if there are many users chatting? Than you

Comment: Well you have to understand that these are two completely different things. With websockets you can handle much trafic, but if you want to keep many connections open, you could use a hybrid system. Use sockets when a client is acitve, if it there is no activity for a while, close the socket and start long polling every 5 minutes or so to check for new messages. A chat app is a very basic and good model to learn about websockets. Please follow some simple nodejs tutorials and you'll understand